# array is decayed as a pointer which is pointing to its first element in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char myName[]{ "Alex" }; // fixed array
    std::cout << myName << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is: Alex

On the other hand, the output of the following code

```
int main()
{
     int array []{ 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 };

     std::cout << array << '\n'; // print memory address of array pointer 
 }
```

is: 0x7ffdf3e66f50
I understand both and then was confused at the same time. So I need more clarifications.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second example.  How did you determine that it "print memory address of array pointer + 1", I've compared variations (`&array`, `array` and `&array[0]`) and they had all the same value.

Comment: @AProgrammer, I have updated it. I mean, print the memory address of the decayed array pointer, which is the memory address of array[0], which is 0x7ffdf3e66f50. What confused me is that, the first one print out the value of the array, which is "Alex"; while the second one prints out the memory address of the first element of the array.

Comment: Ok, the duplicate should then answer your question.